# In Access VBA expression builder, how do I sum a column conditionally?

Tags: ms-access, vba, expressionbuilder

Let's say I have two fields `A` and `B` and one textbox `B_input`. I would like to set up a query so it sums all entries of column `A` where `B = B_input`

Currently I have:

```
==Sum(IIf([B_input]<>"All",[A],IIf([B_input]<>[B],0,[A])))
```

I did more testing, it seem the problem is that under Sum(IIF([B_input])), it's not recognizing the value of [B_input], but if I just have IIF([B_input]), it recognize the value just fine, any ideas?

Comment: We are trying to edit the post at the same time, I'll wait a while before trying to make more changes.

Comment: Thanks, I just added some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up, went with form filtering instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
iif([B_input]=="xyz",Sum[A],False)
```

Might be what you're after but I'm not sure i understood your question properly.

Alternatively, just edit the sql to something like

```
SELECT(SUM[A]) AS SumOfA FROM [MyTable] HAVING ("B"="xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=Sum(IIf([B_input]<>"All",[A],0))
```

Comment: @Yongke Where are you trying to do this? Because that is a fairly standard answer.

Comment: Expression Builder of a textbox in a forum.  Does it have to do with [B_input] is a forum textfield and not a table field?

Comment: @Yongke So what are you summing? Do you mean a textbox in the form footer of a continuous form? Because if not, you need to say exactly what you wish to achieve  - sum may not be the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  I have a textbox at the end of a continous form.  [A] and [B] are columns, while [B_input] is a textbox.  It doesn't seem to recognize the textbox value of [B_input].

Comment: Ok I did more testing, this seem to be the culprit:  =Sum(IIf([B_input],1,2)), it simply does not recognize the value of B_input, but if I have =IIf([B_input],1,2) then it does, any ideas?

Comment: I have just tested with the form footer of a continuous form `=Sum(IIf([AText]="a",[ANumber],0))` and it works as expected. What data type is B_Input? Unless it is YesNo, you need to have a equality there somewhere. If it is YesNo, it may be worth trying `=True`

Comment: B_input is a combo box, but it's value are text.

Comment: I did a test with exactly what you wrote: =Sum(IIf([B_input]="All",1,2)), it throw the same error.  Does combo box make any difference from textfield?

Comment: Are you sure the bound column is text? Just put `=[B_Input]` to test, then use the format in my comment above.

Comment: If I put =[B_input], it get the value just fine.  In fact, it get the value just fine even with =IIf([B_input],1,2), it's just when I wrap a SUM outside of the IIF the error occurs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6445/discussion-between-remou-and-yongke-bill-yu)

Comment: I gave up, I used form filter instead.